# How can I check for apt-get errors in a bash script?

Tags: apt, bash, scripts

I am writing a bash script to install software and update Ubuntu 12.04. I would like the script to be able to check for apt-get errors especially during apt-get update so that I can include corrective commands or exit the script with a message. How can I have my bash script check for these types of errors?

**Edit March 21st:**
Thank you terdon for the providing just the information I needed! Here is the script I created with a combination of your suggestions to check for updates and recheck when errors occur and then report back. I will be adding this to a longer script that I am using to customize new Ubuntu installations.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update

if [ $? != 0 ]; 
then
    echo "That update didn't work out so well. Trying some fancy stuff..."
    sleep 3
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
    apt-get update -f || echo "The errors have overwhelmed us, bro." && exit
fi

echo "You are all updated now, bro!"
```

Comment: I would rather suggest you to use corrective commands themselves if they work in normal conditions.

Comment: What type of errors?

Comment: The line `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf` seems to correct most of the apt-get errors I've encountered. For a less verbose and more quite approach I use `apt-get update -qq` and `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* -f`

Comment: I suppose you don't have to repeate `-f` option for `rm`, so use e.g. `rm -rfv /var/lib/apt/lists/*`, instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest approach is to have your script continue only if `apt-get` exits correctly. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install BadPackageName && 
## Rest of the script goes here, it will only run
## if the previous command was succesful
```

Alternatively, exit if any steps failed:

```
sudo apt-get install BadPackageName || echo "Installation failed" && exit
```

This would give the following output:

```
terdon@oregano ~ $ foo.sh
[sudo] password for terdon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package BadPackageName
Installation failed
```

This is taking advantage of a basic feature of bash and most (if not all) shells:

- `&&` : continue only if the previous command succeeded (had an exit status of 0)
- `||`: continue only if the previous command failed (had an exit status of not 0)

It is the equivalent of writing something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt-get install at

## The exit status of the last command run is 
## saved automatically in the special variable $?.
## Therefore, testing if its value is 0, is testing
## whether the last command ran correctly.
if [[ $? > 0 ]]
then
    echo "The command failed, exiting."
    exit
else
    echo "The command ran succesfuly, continuing with script."
fi
```

Note that if a package is already installed, `apt-get` will run successfully, and the exit status will be 0.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I think I will use the if command so I can have update try again. Thank you!

Comment: I just edited my question to give you credit and clicked the check mark. I will now look over my previous questions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yo can set options to stop your script like this:

```
set -o pipefail  # trace ERR through pipes
set -o errexit   # same as set -e : exit the script if any statement returns a non-true return value
```