# How to stop the bash script when a condition fails?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Here it shows to use the `||` and `&&` in a single line to concatenate the execution of commands: [How can I check for apt-get errors in a bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436908/how-can-i-check-for-apt-get-errors-in-a-bash-script)

I am trying to stop a script execution  if a certain condition fails,

e.g.

```
false || echo "Obvious error because its false on left" && exit
```

Here it prints `Obvious error because its false on the left` and exits the console which is what I wanted.

```
true || echo "This shouldn't print" && exit
```

Here, there's no echo print but the `exit` command runs as well, i.e., the console is closed, shouldn't the `exit` command not run because the echo command on the right was not executed?
Or is by default a statement considered false on the left hand side of an `&&` operator?

Edit:
I should have mentioned it before, my aim was to echo the error and exit if it was not clear.
w.r.t to my specific case of catching errors when grouping conditions using && and ||, @bodhi.zazen answer solves the problem.

@takatakatek answer makes it more clear about the flow control and the bash guide links are excellent

@muru answer has good explanation of why not to use set -e if you want custom error messages to be thrown with alternatives of using perl and trap which I think is a more robust way and see myself using it from my second bash script onwards!

Comment: As far as I can tell it exits as the script is done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want (as pointed out by steeldriver)

```
true || { echo "This shouldn't print" && exit; }
```

Otherwise your script is reading one conditional at at time

a or b and then exit

I think you want a or (b and exit) ?

Comment: Actually, you *must* use `{ ... ; }` (as @steeldriver suggested), or else the `exit` only exits the subshell, and the parent shell continues executing the script.

Comment: I needed a `;` at the end (`{ ... ; };`) to include that statement in a Bash script.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that || and && only skip one subsequent stanza of a command chain when the condition fails. If you write out a full block structure it makes perfect sense. What you wrote becomes this:

```
if ! true ; then
   echo "This shouldn't print"
else
   exit
fi
```

What you want is this:

```
if ! true ; then
   echo "This shouldn't print"
   exit
fi
```

When you are using Bash's shortcut conditional operators it is better to avoid mixing them. The logic is much easier to understand while you're writing it, and your readers will appreciate your good style.

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Control_Operators
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3

Comment: Yes in my opinion this is much more how conditioning in bash should be written

Comment: @takatakatek This makes it more clear why it fails in my case. I agree that the logic is clear in this one but isn't the reason for grouping conditions using && and || is to avoid expressing them using conditional statements ?

Comment: @kosol Yes, && and || combine two things: Testing the exit status of the previous command, and specifying a single command (or command group) to be executed (for &&) or skipped (for ||). They can be useful for very simple cases, but they can not replace fully expressed `if ... then ... elif ... else ... fi` blocks. I suspect you may not be aware that Bash doesn't have true *boolean* types seen in more sophisticated languages. If the exit status of a command is *0* (zero), Bash treats that as *true/success*. If the exit status is non-zero, Bash treats that as *false/failure*.

Answer (score 8):

You could start the script with:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
```

The `-e` ensures that the script exits the moment something returns false (or any non-zero number). A specific failure can then be avoided with `something || true`

Alternatively, if you want to postpone error checking until later in the script, you can use `set -e`:

```
#!/bin/bash
false  # script continues happily
set -e
false  # script stops
```

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to fail on error is to use bash's `-e` option (`set -e` or `/bin/bash -e` in the shebang). However, this doesn't make it easy to send custom error messages. There are a couple of idioms that might make it simpler:

#### `die` à la Perl

Perl has a very convenient [`die` command](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) which prints a message to stderr and raises an exception, which usually leads to the script terminating. You can emulate this:

```
die () {
  ret=$?
  print "%s\n" "$@" >&2
  exit "$ret"
}

false || die "Obvious error because its false on left"
true || die "This shouldn't print"
```

#### `trap` `ERR`

The `trap <command>` command can be used to run a command when a signal is received, or when exiting the script (`trap ... EXIT`), or when a command returns an error (`trap ... ERR`). So something like:

```
trap 'ret=$?; printf "%s\n" "$ERR_MSG" >&2; exit "$ret"' ERR
```

Then:

```
ERR_MSG="Obvious error because its false here"
false
ERR_MSG="This shouldn't print"
true
```

---

In either case, I'd suggest using at least `exit 1`, to indicate that the script *failed*. A plain `exit` will use the exit status of the previous command, which in these cases would be the `echo` or `printf` commands, which would usually succeed. Saving the exit status of the failing command like I have done here would be a nice-to-have.